# Issue with S3 Bucket naming policy and attempting to send SDK generated requests to an API implementing the S3 API

Tags: go, amazon-s3

Apologies if the title wording doesn't properly describe the issue, I wasn't exactly sure how to phrase it.

I am working on an API that can handle requests as though it is the S3 API, and should therefore work with the Go S3 SDK I am specifically encountering a problem when attempting to pass a Bucket name to Go S3 SDK functions.

for example:

```
result, err := svc.CreateBucket(&s3.CreateBucketInput{
    Bucket:aws.String(bucketName),
})
```

when bucket name is set to a string that i believe is being parsed as two separate labels such as `testBucket` or `myBucket` the SDK seems to generate a request with the host address set to the endpoint address i.e. `http://localhost:8000/s3/` followed by the bucket name, which my API can accept, handle, and respond appropriately.

However, when the bucket name contains a string that is parsed as a single label such as `test` or `bucket` or `testbucket` the SDK generates a host address with the bucket name preceding the host i.e. `http://test.localhost:8000/s3/` which results in an error as the API I have written does not support this host address.

Ideally I need to somehow support the use of single label bucket names, either by extending how the API handles requests, or by working out a way to force the SDK to stop changing the host URL format.

If anyone is able to help solve the issue, or offer advice I would be very grateful.

Comment: So I've just replicated your code and have reproduced the issue. I've raised a bug with the SDK team and see if they come back https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/issues/1092

Comment: @ChrisTownsend Thanks for confirming, and reporting it. Hopefully they'll get back soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've stepped through the AWS SDK V2 and the function `moveBucketNameToHost(req.URL, bucket)` is what causes the abnormal host. I'm going to mention this and it's up to AWS to see if this is a bug or not. There is a way around this though!

You need to set the EndpointResolver property `HostnameImmutable` to `true`. This will stop it being changed by this function.

Example:
When making a custom resolver

```
// for custom localstack endpoint
    customResolver := aws.EndpointResolverFunc(func(service, region string) (aws.Endpoint, error) {
        if service == s3.ServiceID {
            return aws.Endpoint{
                PartitionID:   "aws",
                URL:           "http://localhost:4566",
                SigningRegion: "eu-west-1",
                HostnameImmutable: true, // This must be set to true to disable the host changing
            }, nil
        }
        // returning EndpointNotFoundError will allow the service to fallback to it's default resolution
        return aws.Endpoint{}, &aws.EndpointNotFoundError{}
    })

    config, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithRegion("eu-west-1"), config.WithEndpointResolver(customResolver))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to load SDK config, %v", err)
    }

    client := s3.NewFromConfig(config)
```

**UPDATE**

By default, S3 uses virtual host path style to address buckets. This is the reason the host-name is mutated to be {bucketname}.localhost:4566.

S3 has few requirements for a valid bucket name. Accordingly, camelCase is an invalid bucket name as per the requirements, and thus SDK falls back to path-style urls. Thus host-name is not mutated and you see localhost:4566/camelCase.

Coming to your workaround, If HostnameImmutable property is set to true, the SDK API clients will not modify the hostname of the URL. This may cause the API client not to function correctly if the API requires the operation specific hostname values to be used by the client.

A better solution in your case would be to enable UsePathStyle option on S3 options directly

```
result, err :=  client.CreateBucket(ctx, &input, func(o *s3.Options) {
        o.UsePathStyle = true
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, and the example. This makes sense! Noting D. Smith's comment on this thread as-well, it seems like AWS will be depreciating the path-based routing at some point in the future, and since I'd like to avoid requiring API users to use specific options, the best solution will be to somehow implement Virtual Hosting within my API. I'll mark your answer here as correct and post a new question regarding how to best implement virtual hosting on a Go Gin router. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to a change made to the SDK to remove support for path-based bucket routing: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html

You can update the configuration for `Config.S3ForcePathStyle` to have the bucket name as the subdomain (default) or the path. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/#Config

Comment: Thank you for the link to information on VirtualHosting, implementing this will most likely be my next course of action.